# Why "solutions" in "here are two solutions key points"?

Tags: possessives

> Here are two boy's cars.

But.

> Here are two solutions key points.

Why in first example is "'s" used and in second one it's not?

I checked with [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/) and [GoogleTranslate](https://translate.google.com/). I want to explain to key point for the solution of a problem, then used a tools and get confused.

https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/How-to-Make-Possessives-in-English

Or is this correct?

> Here are two solution's key points.

Comment: Where are the examples from? Both are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be plural "solutions", followed by just the possessive apostrophe...

> *Here are two **solutions'** key points.*

We wouldn't normally write or pronounce the possessive ***s*** itself after the apostrophe, so it's an easy mistake to make. Of course, the syntax would be much clearer as...

> *Here are **the key points of two solutions**.*

Syntactically, it's just the same with *two **boys'** cars*, but because *boys' cars* has at least *some* currency, there's no reason to recast that one to *the cars of two boys*.

Comment: If I want to say "two cars of the boy" would it be "two boy's cars"?
Thank you a lot for the previous answer.

Comment: No, you wouldn't say "two boy's cars" in any context I can think of. Well, you'd ***say*** it, because it's indistinguishable from *two **boys'** cars*, as per my answer above, but your version is incorrectly punctuated. The natural alternative to (valid, but "ugly") "two cars of the boy"  is ***the boy's two cars***.